# Getting NULL when open file in C code by JNI in android

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm calling C code by JNI in android app.

Every thing is OK in calling, but when I put this code:

```
FILE* fp = fopen("/storage/sdcard0/input.txt","w+");
if(fp==NULL)
    return(*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"n");
else
    return(*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"y");
```

it gets "n". I'm sure that the path is true and I tried this command on my mobile's terminal:

```
cat /storage/sdcard0/input.txt
```

and it got me the file's contents.

**Edit:**

I tried to change the permission of the file by this code but it gave me the same response:

```
void changePerm()
{
    Process chperm;
    try {
        chperm=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");


   DataOutputStream os = 
          new DataOutputStream(chperm.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes("chmod 777 /storage/sdcard0/input.txt\n");
        os.flush();

        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();

          chperm.waitFor();

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

I also add this permission and no thing changed:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Have you tried breaking down your statements to see which line is causing trouble?

Comment: Have you looked into permissions? What makes you think your app has permissions to read/write from the root of your external storage?

Comment: @Al-mo there is no need to do that because I know whats going on. fopen() return null. I want to know why?

Comment: @Erik I don't looked into permissions. but when you do add code that need permission, the program stops not get null. Am I right?

Comment: Not really... it depends where your file is located. If it's located in a public area or in one of you apps folders, it should be ok.
I suggest you read up on external storage here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: I'll edit the question to show u what I tried to get permission. However it doesn't help me

Comment: Like I said: it depends on the location of the file. Here's how you can retrieve your apps external storage directory:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: And thank god that Android will not give su permissions to just any app (and that includes yours) :)

Comment: It is entirely possible that your hard coded path is incorrect **for an application**.  On recent Android versions, the ADB shell you tested with **sees different filesystem mounts** than apps do.  You should not be hard coding the external storage path anyway - discovery it with the Java API and pass it into the native code.  As a simple check, download a file manager app from the market and try to browse the file with that, as it should have the same view of public filesystems that your app (with external storage permission) can have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it that the permissions on the file are in fact `0777`.

You added `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, but you try to open for writing

```
FILE* fp = fopen("/storage/sdcard0/input.txt","w+");
```

You can get the error by checking for `errno` and get a message with [`strerror`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strerror.html).

You must either open the file for *reading* only `"r"` or add permission for writing [`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)